# Why arrayformula makes empty cells not empty even if empty?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: screenshot]

What do I do? i did hide the 0s by checking the sum, is there a better way? Yes the arrayformula gives the cell a formula so isblank() returns false right?

i just want the m column to be empty if there are no input in k, l

i tried count but apparently it counted the nonempty cells in the column

=ArrayFormula(IF(AND(COUNT(K:K)=1,count(L:L)=1), K:K+L:L, ""))

thanks all in advance!

Formulas I tried:
=ArrayFormula(IF(AND(TRIM(K:K)="",TRIM(L:L)=""), , K:K+L:L))
=ArrayFormula(IF(AND(K:K="", L:L=""), , K:K+L:L)) doesn't work

=ArrayFormula(IF(K:K="", , K:K+L:L)) works except L column numbers, how do I add L to the formula?

Answer (score 4):

Your original formula returned `""`, i.e., a zero-length text string. That is not considered a truly blank value by functions such as `counta()`. To get a truly blank value, use `iferror(1/0)` like this:

```
=if( "cows" = "home", "they came home!", iferror(1/0) )
```

Alternatively, omit the parameter altogether by entering a comma and not following with a value, as in

```
=if( "cows" = "home", "they came home!", )
```

The result will be the same although the former makes the intention clearer by explicitly showing that a `null` value will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with:

=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IF(LEN(K:K)+Len(L:L)=0, , K:K+L:L)))