# Why does ARRAYFORMULA populate a date in cells that seem to be excluded from evaluation with IF phrase?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my spreadsheet, Column F calculates the number of workdays between the Start Date in Column A and the End Date in Column B.  I used the following formula in F2:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($A$2:$A),"",NETWORKDAYS($A$2:$A,$B$2:$B)))

If the total number of workdays is greater than 1, Column I adds a workday to the Start Date.  This is the formula I am using in I2:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF($F$2:$F>1,WORKDAY($A2:$A,1),""))

[image: Sample Sheet]

As the screenshot shows, the date 1/1/1900 is displayed in all the rows that have the value "".  For some reason, the
`IF($F$2:$F>1)` part of the formula does not seem to be functioning as expected.  If I change the formula in I2 to

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF($F$2:$F>1,WORKDAY($A2:$A,**2**),""))

then the date 1/2/1900 is displayed, which seems to indicate that the original formula in I2 is determining that in all the cells in F2:F with the value "", the value is greater than 1.

I figured out how to resolve it here:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67171260/why-arrayformula-makes-empty-cells-not-empty-even-if-empty](https://stackoverflow.com), but I would like to understand why cells with the value "" have a value seemingly greater than 1.  Can someone explain this behavior or point out where I my thinking is off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *A blank cell is taken for value `0`; you can test it by pointing at an empty cell say `A1` and enter this formula in **B1** `=value(A1)`
  which comes out as `0`*
- *at the same time number `0` equates to the date `Sat, 30 December 1899` when represented in date-format style & when your formula is adding `1` **workday** to the empty cell, the output is bound to be `Mon, 1 January 1900`*
- *a [short article](https://www.iwpcug.org/docs/18991230.php) on why `0` **=** `30-dec-1899` & an excerpt is pasted below:*

> So when Microsoft program designers thought of choosing a date for the
> start of their day numbering system, they thought of the first day of
> the 20th century, which was 1 January 1900. But this was to be day 1,
> not day zero. That made day zero 31st December 1899.
>
> Whether they overlooked the fact that the year 1900 is not a leap year
> or whether they deliberately ignored the complication, I do not know,
> but their algorithm for working out the day number from the date
> assumes the year 1900 was a leap year. It was not. Thus all day
> numbers prior to 1 March 1900 are incorrect by one day. This makes the
> base date (day zero) 30th rather than 31st December 1899. This explains why 30th December 1899 is the base date for Microsoft Works database and spreadsheet programs.

Comment: I understand that.  However, my formula is saying "if F2:F is greater than 1, then add a workday, otherwise leave blank" is it not?  As a result, I would expect the cells in I6:I to display the same value as cells I3 and I4, or Dec. 30 1899, because they don't meet the IF criteria.  But if I change the formula to add two workdays "if F2:F is greater than 1", the value in cells I6:I display Jan 2, 1900.  Why are the values in cells in F6:F considered greater than 1?

Comment: this part of the formula in your Column_F `IF(ISBLANK($A$2:$A),"",` is not a *true blank value* and would test `TRUE` for condition `>1`(referring to blank cells induced by the formula); instead use `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($A$2:$A),,NETWORKDAYS($A$2:$A,$B$2:$B)))` and you should see the difference

Comment: I understand that it is not a true blank value, but if you would forgive my density, can you explain why F6 tests `TRUE` for condition `>1`?  I know how to get the desired output, I am just trying to grasp the concept.

Comment: the `""` is a text string with null length and within spreadsheets ecosystem text takes precedence(hierarchy) over integer values & so quintessentially  `""` **>** `1` or even a super high value of `""` **>** `99^99`