# How to add events to Google Calendar from Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a form of table created in Google Sheets, as following:

Columns:

```
Event Title  | Start Date | Start Time | End Date | End Time | Description | Time Zone
```

Sample Record:

```
TEST EVENT | 5/23/2024 Thu | 1:00 PM | 5/23/2024,Thu | 3:00 PM | NA | GMT +3
```

Providing Google Script API code with example to solve this problem, will be enough.

Comment: I have deleted the answer since I identified that there was a date formatting issue. I'll try to work on this and get back with a viable solution instead

Answer (score 1):

### Google Calendar: Add Events from Google Sheets

**UPDATE:**

This sample script checks today's date on your Google Sheet and sends an email to your specified email address.

```
const myFunction = () => {

  // Gets your current active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Gets the calendar of the given ID. Note: Replace "id" with your calendar ID
  var calendarID = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("id");
  // Declares the range to be used and gets its value from the spreadsheet
  var range = ss.getRange("A2:G4").getValues();

  // Loops through the rows and combines Column B with Column C and Column G, as well as Column D with Column E and Column G
  range.forEach(row => {
    var title = row[0];
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

    var startMonth = months[new Date(row[1]).getMonth()]; 
    var startDay = new Date(row[1]).getDate(); 
    var startYear = new Date(row[1]).getFullYear(); 
    var startDate = startMonth + " " + startDay + ", " + startYear + " " + row[2] + ":00" + " " + row[6]; 

    var endMonth = months[new Date(row[3]).getMonth()]; 
    var endDay = new Date(row[3]).getDate(); 
    var endYear = new Date(row[3]).getFullYear(); 
    var endDate = endMonth + " " + endDay + ", " + endYear + " " + row[4] + ":00" + " " + row[6]; 
    var description = row[5];
    
    // Creates the events with the given title, start date, end date, and description from the spreadsheet
    calendarID.createEvent(title, new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate), {description: description});
  })

}
```

**NOTE:**

Column C and Column E should be formatted in PLAIN TEXT for the date conversion in this script to work properly.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getcalendarbyidid

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried to execute the code, but still I'm facing a problem is that dates are not correctly added to the calendar. in sheet date is 23-may-2024, while it is added in 1970 !, can you help in that, note that my calendar timezone is 'Asia/Riyadh'.

Comment: You may need to double check the date formatting within your Google Sheets. Entries like `5/23/2024,Thu` is not recognized as a date format due to the comma that separates the date and the day itself. You may read this [article](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats) regarding the supported formats for Google Apps Script.

Comment: @abdulrahman I have updated my answer, and see if this works well as a sample

Comment: Event is added but with an old date(1970) & incorrect time.
Check the following part code, with its logs and output, that may unfold the reason of the problem for you:

`var startMonth = months[new Date(row[1]).getMonth()]; 
 Logger.log("startMonth: " + startMonth);
 var startDay = new Date(row[1]).getDate();
 Logger.log("startDay: " + startDay);
 var startYear = new Date(row[1]).getFullYear(); 
 Logger.log("startYear: " + startYear);
 var startDate = startMonth + " " + startDay + ", " + startYear + " " + row[2] + ":00" + " " + row[6]; 
Logger.log("startDate: " + startDate);`

Comment: Continue:  


Log output:
4:20:19 PM Info startMonth: May  
4:20:19 PM Info startDay: 23  
4:20:19 PM Info startYear: 2024  
4:20:19 PM Info startDate: May 23, 2024 Sat Dec 30 1899 13:00:00 GMT+0521 (India Standard Time):00 GMT +3  
NOTE THAT my calendar's timezone is already set as GMT+3, while logs shows something regarding India Standard Time.

Comment: I think it's because based on the sample output, the start time and end time should be in `PLAIN TEXT` format.

Comment: do you think converting date to text via code will solve this issue?

Comment: The reason why we chose with the plain text formatting with this sample script is so that we can simply build the necessary date format needed as a parameter for the `createEvent`  method. Now the reason why the log outputs the date `Dec 30 1899 13:00:00 GMT+0521 (India Standard Time)` is related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76916363/why-does-arrayformula-populate-a-date-in-cells-that-seem-to-be-excluded-from-eva).

Comment: More so, yes it is possible to convert date to text via coding logic and simply extract the time from the text using regular expressions. You are free to explore any other ways to tackle the problem